# Connect PhalconPHP with Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, frameworks, phalcon

What is the sequence I have to follow in order to integrate PhalconPHP with Parse.com (the php SDK)?

If is it possible how will I access to it?

I have seen that there is an Parse PHP SDK with classes helping us to do requests to Parse Backend.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically a same way as to integrate PHP with parse.com. By following [first section](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/php) of the tutorial you will be able to get SDK classes via `\Parse` namespace. When installed, it's your choice to wrap an `Injectable` service around it and hook it to `di` or to use it as it is.

Comment: So all i have to do is hook it in the DI and it is done?